# Get remaining hours after a specific time period

Tags: datediff, dateadd

The table below has three fields namely
**PID is pass Id**, **D is the duration in (hrs)** on that pass, then checkin in the time that PID has actually been given access to visit,

```
PID     D       CHECKIN                 

PS1005  1   2015-08-16 10:11:38.027
PS1006  3   2015-08-16 13:03:41.137
PS1007  6   2015-08-16 02:09:30.273
PS1008  3   2015-08-16 15:51:38.527
PS1009  4   2015-08-16 17:03:41.217
PS1010  1   2015-08-16 08:33:30.723
```

the trick here is to create a third
row that displays how many hours are remaining on that **PID** against the current date time. the count should go up to 0, no negatives ie like

```
PID     D       CHECKIN         REMAINING_HRS                         

PS1005  1   2015-08-16 10:11:38.027     0
PS1006  3   2015-08-16 13:03:41.137     1
PS1007  6   2015-08-16 02:09:30.273     3
PS1008  3   2015-08-16 15:51:38.527     1
PS1009  4   2015-08-16 17:03:41.217     2
PS1010  1   2015-08-16 08:33:30.723     0
```

i have tried using dateAdd and Datediff function as below

```
SELECT j.PID, 
j.D, 
j.CHECKIN, 
IIF(j.TL <= 0, '0', j.TL) AS REMAINING_HRS 

FROM (SELECT PID, 

D, CHECKIN, 
CAST(DATEDIFF(hour,
GETDATE(),
DATEADD(HH,a.D,aCHECKIN) AS int) TL
FROM TABLE1 a ) as j
```

but am not so sure about my results, i wanted a more proffessional and cleaner way of doing it without writting unessesary lines
of query

Comment: Can you show us the SQL you have so far?   Then people can recommend improvements or alternate ways of doing it.

Comment: i added it in the question